# After designing an autopilot, how does it affect aircraft modes?

Tags: flight-controls, stability, autopilot

Let's say an autopilot will be designed for the longitudinal axis. A pitch attitude hold will be made with a sas in the inner loop and a pid in the outer loop. How does this system change the phugoid and short period characteristics of the aircraft? To understand this, is it enough to look at theta and q outputs for a given theta reference? Can it be thought of as theta response for phugoid and q response for short period?